# GeoDataApi Android: Advantage over manually calling directly to google

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am able to manually fetching addresses using HttpUrlConnection to connect to Google but when I looked at the Google Place API document for android there is a GeoDataApi which can do the same thing but require Google Play Service. Does that mean the user who installed my apk require Google Play Service.

Comment: I think if you will add google play service as a library in your application and use it in code, user has to download it unless that piece of code want run and your app will crash...

Comment: So is it better for me just use the httpurlconnection to connect to google places api instead of using GeoDataApi for android, coz apart from this part I don't need to use any other google play services.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Someone need to require the google play service installed when you try to use the `GeoDataApi`. If you just use the `HttpUrlConnection`, you can do the requests to the web api sever and get the JSON data, and I think that dont need the google play services.